# Didn't receive tax refund due to incorrect account number

Tags: united-states, bank-account, income-tax-refund

I requested the IRS to send my 2021 refund to two different accounts, in one of them it came through just fine. In the other, I wrote the wrong account # so it never came to me. (it's a vanguard account) Vanguard support keeps telling me that I never got it but they seem too busy to try tracing it down in their logs despite I have the date that the IRS claims that it came through. Over the past few weeks I have repeatedly called the IRS and I never get close to getting anyone to talk to. The system keeps telling me about how busy they are and to try their automated services which displays that I got the money in BOTH accounts but it's not true for the vanguard account.

What can I do to get the second amount? FYI, I live abroad and do not want a check sent to me. I just want to give them another account # to send it to.

Comment: The IRS followed your instructions;  why would they have any obligation to pay the amount again?

Comment: You will have to get the incorrect recipient (or its bank) to reject the payment; otherwise the IRS will not do anything ever. If a request to pay again would work, you could just keep giving them new numbers over and over, and get the refund over and over...

Comment: @DJohnM, if the account # is incorrect, can't the IRS see a rejected transfer of funds and simple accept a new account #? But without being able to talk to anyone at the IRS, how can I work this out? Is anyone able to speak to someone there?

Comment: Why do you believe that the erroneous number you supplied is not an active one,?  If it is active, do you believe the account holder would immediately report this free money from the IRS?

Comment: Not sure why you are in doubt but FYI, I copied and pasted the account number from my account profile. That is 100% my account #. However, unlike my bank, Vanguard gives a different account number when doing an external deposit. It's much longer. I don't have it in front of me so it's possible it's just my account # with a longer prefix. Regardless, I forgot about it and gave the IRS my regular account #.